# Dynamic localization using JSTL

Tags: dynamic, jstl, locale

Could you please suggest me an idea for performing dynamic localization using JSTL format tag (setLocale).

For example I have a radio button or dropdown list box containing some language codes such as en, es if the user select the any one of the language the whole web page turns to selected language. Is is possible to do that using below code such that my language to be updated dynamically in that value attribute.

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en" />
```